# How do I conditionally apply CSS to a class if a different class is present?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following in the view:

```
<div class="bottom-nav container-fluid">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row mobile-menu-row">
   <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mobile-menu-row">
   <div class="slidedown"></div>
  </div>
```

Slidedown and Slideup are both present depending on the user clicking on the button. At the moment I have a height of 440px applied to bottom-nav that is massive and really only want to be present on bottom-nav if Slidedown is present and the screen size is under 768px. Any suggestion on only applying CSS styling on another class if a class appears?

Attempts that I've tried that definitely didn't work:

```
@media and (max-width: 767px) {
  .bottom-nav .slidedown{
   height: 440px; 
  }
 }
```

This naturally doesn't work because it's applying it to slidedown and not the bottom-nav section.

My JS file has:

```
const nav = () => {
const mobileButton = document.querySelector('a.mobile-button');
const menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-cont');
const regionLink = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-row ul > li');
const regionMenu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-row ul > li > ul');
const bottom = document.getElementsByClassName('bottom-nav');

function init() {
  mobileButton.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
  regionLink.addEventListener('click', toggleSubMenu);
}

let toggleMenu = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (menu.classList.contains('slideup')) {
    menu.classList = 'slidedown';
  } else {
    menu.classList = 'slideup';
  }
};
if (menu.classList = 'slidedown'){
  bottom.setAttribute("style", "height: 440px;")
} else {
  bottom.setAttribute("style","height: 0;")
}
```

I thought the condition would work but it appears to just break many different things on the page.

I've also tried:

```
    let toggleMenu = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (menu.classList.contains('slideup')) {
       menu.classList = 'slidedown';
       bottom.setAttribute("style", "height: 440px;")
     } else {
       menu.classList = 'slideup';
       bottom.setAttribute("style", "height: inherit;")
     }
   };
```

This messes up a lot of my other JS on the page.

Comment: Didn't you try any code that you can show us?
Have you though about media queries?

Comment: Valid point. I edited the question and added in my current JS that is doing the toggling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were close! Instead of squashing the full style attribute of your `bottom` elem, just set the `height` property, and likewise, instead of replacing the `className` of `menu`, just add to and subtract from the class name:

```
let toggleMenu = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (menu.classList.contains('slideup')) {
    menu.className = menu.className.replace('slideup', '');
    menu.className += ' slidedown';
    bottom.style.height = '440px';
  } else {
    menu.className = menu.className.replace('slidedown', '');
    menu.className += ' slideup';
    bottom.style.height = 'inherit';
  }
};
```

Comment: I ended up doing bottom.setAttribute on both. I'll test out the style.height instead

Comment: Is there a way to do this with CSS only? I mean applying a CSS class only if another CSS class is present?

Comment: Well sure, you can do `.class-one.class-two { background: red; }` --- is that what you mean?